# Django auth backends and auto login

Tags: django, authentication, registration, backend

I'm trying to have a user login automatically as soon as they register. They have just input their desired username and two matching passwords and I would like to grant access to the site with no more friction. But my current view with an authenticate followed by a login using authenticate's user object doesn't work i.e. the view redirects to the profile page after register, but the profile page is `@login_required` decorator protected, and so redirects because the login was unsuccessful. I have widely debugged and looked around.

I've tried everything I can think of short of resorting to a third-party registration app. People have suggested there's a problem/peculiarity with the backends or something, but I just can't see why I can't register, auth and login in one view.

views.py (relevant parts)

```
@login_required
def user(request, user_id):
    profile_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id) 
    context = RequestContext(request)    
    context['profile_user'] = profile_user
    return render_to_response('profile.html', context)


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],
                                    password = request.POST['password1'])
            if new_user is not None:
                login(request, new_user)
                context = RequestContext(request)    
                context['user_id'] = new_user.id
                context['new_user'] = new_user
                url = '/user/%s/' % new_user.id      
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How do you deal with this?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing as you (authenticate() then login()) and it works fine in my app.  Sorry this isn't very helpful - but you're definitely on the right track.

Comment: That's heartbreaking news in one way, because I've tried everything to sort this out. It's starting to feel personal.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by:

1. Redirecting to an intermediate template through simple view, it will set the session cookie on client side, you can show a message like "Registration completed. logging in..."
2. Redirect to profile page after a small 3-5 seconds time out. This time, request will carry authentication cookie, profile page will be accessible.

Comment: If you redirect you cannot carry the POST variables with you, right? So the password would be lost before the next view could use it to login.

Comment: but the user will have already logged in inside view "register". When you show an intermediate page AFTER "register", the session will be stored on client too as a cookie, and cookie will be sent back by browser to next view..in your case "user". User view will read that session cookie and authenticate user, no password will be needed.